# how web server overcome limited socket port number

Tags: web-services, sockets

> A given server normally creates only one listening socket, which
>   then exists for the lifetime of the server. **The kernel creates one
>   connected socket for each client connection that is accepted**

I'm new to socket programming, and reading above on the book, since port number is limited to 1-65535, every connection consume one and there is of course more concurrent connection than this, how can web server overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new to socket programming, and reading above on the book, since port number is limited to 1-65535, every connection consume one

No. Every inbound connection uses the same port as the listening port. The book is talking about new sockets, not new ports. You misread.

> and there is of course more concurrent connection than this, how can web server overcome this problem.

There is no problem to overcome.